# Order of compound particles

Tags: particle-と, compounds, particle-まで

I came across the following sentence:

> 彼氏と大喧嘩して、お前とはもう別れたい*とまで*言われた。

Why are と and まで in that order?
Would "別れたい*までと*言われた" be incorrect?
Is there a rule concerning the order in which particles must be assembled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the order matters. Since things before the と will be treated as a part of the quote, お前とはもう別れたいまでと言われた sounds like he actually said "別れたいまで", which makes no sense in this context. It's somewhat like "He even said that ～" vs "He said that even ～". In general, when two particles are combined, the order is almost always important (e.g., you can say 学校では but not 学校はで).

Comment: So as a rule of thumb, I can remember that と is said before まで in order to mark the end of the quote?

Comment: @Rightleg Yes, unless まで is really a part of the quote.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!