# Classification, compounding, and order of particles

Tags: grammar, particles

I read [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76301/what-does-%E6%9C%AC%E7%95%AA-mean-here/76338) that 日本語の勉強は常用漢字を全部覚えてからが本番だ。is a valid sentence but 日本語の勉強は常用漢字を全部覚えてから**の**が本番だ。is not. This reminded me of a question I once had. I do understand that particles are classified into [different types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_particles) <s>(but a person with no linguistic background like me most probably doesn't understand how they are classified)</s> and are better explained in the Japanese Wikipedia [article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E). Can particles of the same type be joined together?

There was already a [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69612/order-of-compound-particles) concerning this before; I was wondering if **there's a general rule concerning compounding them and how this relates to the particle classification.**

Answer (score 1):

1. 常用漢字を全部覚えてからが本番だ
2. 常用漢字を全部覚えてからの(方が)が本番だ

On your second example isn't too bad, if you don't omit the word which should be written in between.
Now #1 means 'The real take begins after remembering...' and #2 means 'The things become much more real/harder after you remembered...' and these two are different.

1. もう別れたいと言われた
2. もう別れたいとまで言われた

From the example, I see the phrase given has an original simple version.
'I was said she wanted to breakup with me.'
And now とまで is added, you should get it とまで is an abbreviation of ということまで. This case the listener was said something else before or it should not be deserved in his opinion. So he needed to exaggerate like this.

---

All these examples, when you see the sentence is a little out of general structure form, we need to find what is hidden after the particle and try to complete it.
Besides, the sentence is written by a grammatical error. We understood it was a misuse.
Anyway, てにをは is the most difficult thing on the Japanese grammar, thousands of exceptions and idiomatic/colloquial uses. Sometimes they follow rules, and some other time just because people say so.

The language can hardly be completely systematic.